# Android apk testing without Robotium

Tags: android, testing, robotium

Hi is it possible to test an apk ( android application ) whose source is not available. without using robotium, roboelectric or to be more specific can this be achieved using just the android default test framework. any help would be of Great value thanks ...

Comment: Hi Daniel, You can try robotium now.. i can share the document if you want... it is very easy to do things now..

Comment: @Chandra i have already created a framework above Robotium this was long back ... thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do by monkeyrunner.. but that is having lot of disadvantages...but still you can do without pain...